# Flutter: How to unit testing moor/drift?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-moor, drift

I already implementation of Drift for local storage, and want make it testable function. But I get stack and idk how to fix it the unit test.

HomeDao

```dart
@DriftAccessor(tables: [RepositoriesTable])
class HomeDao extends DatabaseAccessor<AppDatabase> with _$HomeDaoMixin {
  HomeDao(AppDatabase db) : super(db);

  Future<List<RepositoriesTableData>> getRepositories() async =>
      await select(repositoriesTable).get();
}
```

AppDatabase

```dart
@DriftDatabase(
  tables: [RepositoriesTable],
  daos: [HomeDao],
)
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
  AppDatabase() : super(_openConnection());

  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;
}

QueryExecutor _openConnection() {
  return SqfliteQueryExecutor.inDatabaseFolder(
    path: 'db.sqlite',
    logStatements: true,
  );
}
```

LocalDataSources

```dart
abstract class GTHomeLocalDataSource {
  const GTHomeLocalDataSource();

  Future<List<RepositoriesTableData>> getRepositories();
}

class GTHomeLocalDataSourceImpl implements GTHomeLocalDataSource {
  final AppDatabase appDatabase;

  const GTHomeLocalDataSourceImpl({required this.appDatabase});

  @override
  Future<List<RepositoriesTableData>> getRepositories() async =>
      await appDatabase.homeDao.getRepositories();
}
```

UnitTesting

```dart
void main() => testGTHomeLocalDataSource();

class MockDatabaseHandler extends Mock implements AppDatabase {}

void testGTHomeLocalDataSource() {
  late GTHomeLocalDataSource localDataSource;
  late AppDatabase databaseHandler;

  setUp(() {
    databaseHandler = MockDatabaseHandler();
    localDataSource = GTHomeLocalDataSourceImpl(
      appDatabase: databaseHandler,
    );
  });

  group("GTHomeLocalDataSource -", () {
    test(''' \t
      GIVEN Nothing
      WHEN call getRepositories
      THEN databaseHandler select function has been called and return list of RepositoriesTableData
      ''', () async {
      // GIVEN
      when(() => databaseHandler.homeDao.getRepositories())
          .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(repositoriesDummyTable));

      // WHEN
      final result = await localDataSource.getRepositories();

      // THEN
      verify(() => databaseHandler.homeDao.getRepositories());

      expect(result, isA<List<RepositoriesTableData>>());
      expect(result.length, repositoriesDummyTable.length);
      expect(result.first.language, repositoriesDummyTable.first.language);
    });
  });

  tearDown(() async {
    await databaseHandler.close();
  });
}
```

My function is work well for get data from the local db and show it in the app, but when running as unit test, I stacked with this error.

```
package:gt_core/local/database/database_module.g.dart 424:22           MockDatabaseHandler.homeDao
package:gt_home/data/data_sources/gt_home_local_datasource.dart 20:25  GTHomeLocalDataSourceImpl.getRepositories
test/data/data_sources/gt_home_local_datasource_test.dart 35:44        testGTHomeLocalDataSource.<fn>.<fn>
test/data/data_sources/gt_home_local_datasource_test.dart 29:12        testGTHomeLocalDataSource.<fn>.<fn>
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<void>'
package:drift/src/runtime/api/db_base.dart 125:16                MockDatabaseHandler.close
test/data/data_sources/gt_home_local_datasource_test.dart 47:27  testGTHomeLocalDataSource.<fn>
test/data/data_sources/gt_home_local_datasource_test.dart 46:12  testGTHomeLocalDataSource.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                                       _completeOnAsyncError
test/data/data_sources/gt_home_local_datasource_test.dart        testGTHomeLocalDataSource.<fn>
test/data/data_sources/gt_home_local_datasource_test.dart 46:12  testGTHomeLocalDataSource.<fn>

type 'Future<List<RepositoriesTableData>>' is not a subtype of type 'HomeDao'
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mocking to test Drift database, then you'll need to mock the method call as well, otherwiser the method will return `null` which is the default behavior for Mockito. For example.

```dart
// return rowid
when(db.insertItem(any)).thenAnswer((_) => 1);
```

However it is recommended as per Drift [documentation](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/docs/testing/) to use in-memory sqlite database which doesn't require real device or simulator for testing.

This issue was also has been discussed [here](https://github.com/simolus3/drift/issues/441)

Using in memory database

```dart
import 'package:drift/native.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

import 'package:my_app/src/database.dart'; 

void main() {
  MyDatabase database;
  MyRepo repo;

  setUp(() {
    database = MyDatabase(NativeDatabase.memory());
    repo = MyRepo(appDatabase: database);
  });

  tearDown(() async {
    await database.close();
  });

  group('mytest', () {
    test('test create', () async {
      await repo.create(MyDateCompanion(title: 'some name'));

      final list = await repo.getItemList();
      expect(list, isA<MyDataObject>())
    })
  });
}
```